# SQL - Column to Row conversion in Report

Tags: sql, recursive-query

I have a table with student-name and student-city only. This table is used to find out which student has enrolled online-course from which city.

Table - StudentCity

```
Name               City

Anand              Mumbai

Vinod              Mumbai

Shailesh           Pune

Rupali             Delhi

Annavi             Pune

Arunabha           Kolkata
```

I need the report in the following format:

```
Mumbai    Pune      Delhi   Kolkata

Anand   

Vinod
          Shailesh
                    Rupali
          Annavi
                            Arunabha
```

I am trying to find out a way so that I can use recursive SQL for this. But till now have not succeeded.

Can someone help me out on this.

Comment: `PIVOT` is your friend here.

Comment: To get an improved answer you should add your table schema and some data.

Comment: @mcNets There is sufficent table schema and data to reproduce the scenario.

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny yes, but I usually try to add the 'create table and insert' statements, just to avoid this work to the users that are trying to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take my comment back. You can do this instead :

```
SELECT
     CASE City WHEN 'Mumbai' THEN Name END  AS Mumbai,
     CASE City WHEN 'Pune' THEN Name END AS Pune,
     CASE City WHEN 'Delhi' THEN Name END AS Delhi,
     CASE City WHEN 'Kolkata' THEN Name END AS Kolkata
FROM tab
```

You can see this in action here -> http://rextester.com/NYZH51845

Hope this help!!!

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Comment: For a table with unknown number of 'cities' listed, I guess this hardcoded 'city names' would not work. In such a case what should be the approach?

Comment: Generate the same statement as dynamic SQL.